# Is the hermitian distance always a decreasing function of the inner product of normed vectors?

Tags: inner-products

Using Euclidian distance and dot product definitions, we can easily see that distance decreases when dot product increases and vice versa. Is that the case for hermitian distances vs inner products of normed vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ ? How can we prove it ?

Comment: Distance of what to what and dot product of what with what?

Comment: As said in the question: "of normed vectors".
:)

Comment: $\|u-v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|u\|^2-2\,\text{Re}(u,v)=2(1-\text{Re}(u,v))$, so yes, if you insert "the real part of dot product".

Comment: @Conifold Argh sorry... I meant "the inner product module" (we can't compare complex numbers with real numbers, obviously...).

Comment: I am guessing "module" means absolute value, and with that it is false even in real spaces.

Comment: Damned you're right of course... I'll have to review my notes. Thanks.

Comment: ...and I meant "modulus", which is the same as "absolute value", right ?